# Apply watch on a variable when it is initialized

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to apply the following $watch on an variable when it is initialized, currently **angular** tries to initialize it right away.

How do i achieve this feat?

$watch

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
        return $scope.character.level;
    }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if(newVal > oldVal) {
            resetSkillPoints();
        }
    });
```

$scope.character.level is initialized the moment a user selects a character from a dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to wait for the user to select something before it's initialized.
You should initialize the variable yourself

```
$scope.character = $scope.character || {};

$scope.$watch(function () {
    return $scope.character.level;
}, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if(newVal > oldVal) {
        resetSkillPoints();
    }
});
```

With

```
$scope.character = $scope.character || {};
```

It is saying, make $scope.character = $scope.character but if $scope.character doesn't exist then initialize it to an empty object {}.  This way, if $scope.character already exists you are not overriding it and if it doesnt exist you initialize it.